# Batch file - Syntax error - rename files with loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax, rename

I am trying to rename a lot of files with a batch file.
Example:
Old file name: "document 2133.pdf"
New file name: "document_NewFile_document 2133.pdf"

New file name contains first part of the old file name, an extension ("NewFile") and the complete old file name.

The problem is that only with "echo" my batch is working - but not with "rename":

```
for %%i in (all/*.*) do for /f %%u in ("%%~ni") do (
   echo "%%i" "%%u_NewFile_%%~xi"
)
```

If I change "echo" into "rename" -> Syntax error.

Comment: So what is the output as long as the `echo` is in place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, works without hard-coding a path (except for the all folder):

```
@echo off
for %%i in (all/*.*) do for /f %%u in ("%%~ni") do (
   rename "%%~dpiall\%%~nxi" "%%u_NewFile_%%~nxi"
)
```

Comment: @DennisvanGils, I try your example and it's not working I have 4 files that have an ext of .cfx that I am trying to bulk rename I have a working folder that it looks in like so `%EFM_TEMP%` how can I rename all of the existing files using your for loop

Answer (score 0):

For the rename command you'll need to specify the full path to the %%i file.

For example:

```
 for %%i in (all/*.*) do for /f %%u in ("%%~ni") do (
rename "c:\temp\all\%%i" "%%u_NewFile_%%~xi"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
cd all
for %%i in (*.*) do for /f %%u in ("%%i") do (
    ren "%%i" "%%u_NewFile_%%i"
)
```